# Real-time data synchronization from Azure database to Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: sql, azure, synchronization, azure-synapse

I've done a fair bit of reading and it seems like there are a couple of off-the-shelf products that replicate/sync data from on-premise database to Azure SQL Data Warehouse but I've found nothing that syncs using an Azure database as the source.  The Azure Data Factory holds some promise however it looks more suited to one off loads.

Anyone know of a way? (SSIS package not really an option as I want the transfer to occur wholly inside the cloud)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Data Factory can run continuous loads from SQL Database to SQL Data Warehouse. You'll want to look into the frequency and interval parameters for the pipeline

The documentation is here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-create-datasets/.

Comment: I was asked this question recently.  The maximum interval you can set Azure Data Factory at the moment is 15 minutes, so not real-time, or even near-real time.  Is there an update on this?  Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the real time sync to a data warehouse? I can help but a little context would be helpful.